# Typing special character in password on OS with default keyboard

Tags: linux, keyboard, special-characters

I'm trying to log into my CentOS server using KVM. The OS has default keyboard (US one, I guess) and my password contains local character ([this one](http://graphemica.com/%C5%82)) that is not avaliable in the US keyboard. How can I type it? I tried copy-pasting, didn't work, and I tried to use alt codes on numpad - but this char isn't available there apparently.

Is there any way to input special character in this case?